# How to plot a heatmap of a big matrix with matplotlib (45K * 446)

Tags: python, matplotlib, bigdata, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heatmap of a big microarray dataset (45K rows per 446 columns).
Using `pcolor` from matplotlib I am unable to do it because my pc goes easily out of memory (more than 8G)..

I'd prefer to use python/matplotlib instead of R for personal opinion..
Any way to plot heatmaps in an efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: down sample (it get's down sampled on display anyway, you don't have a 45k tall monitor) or get more RAM.  I deal with 140k x 4k arrays, which take ~25G, to display and do a combination of those two.  You might also get somewhere with imshow + only showing a small section of the data + update on pan.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually I think that the most scalable solution is down sampling.

Comment: could you please give more details about a practical solution? thanks

Comment: @msalem I added the answer below. This question was created circa 3 years ago so I cannot include more than what I remember as my solution.

Comment: I have better experiences with `imshow` for very large grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by downsampling the matrix to a smaller matrix.
I decided to try two methodologies:

- supposing I want to down-sample a matrix of 45k rows to a matrix of 1k rows, I took a row value every 45 rows
- another methodology is, to down-sample 45k rows to 1k rows, to group the 45k rows into 1k groups (composed by 45 adjacent rows) and to take the average for each group as representative row

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said above, this question was created circa 3 years ago so I cannot include more than what I remember as my solution. However, I think it is pretty straightforward to write the code as explained in the answer.